# Concatenate an input of 27 fields to the output of the LSTM layer using Keras in Python

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have an existing LSTM model that looks as follows:

```
model_glove1 = Sequential()
model_glove1.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, 25, input_length=50, weights=[embedding_matrix25],trainable=False))
model_glove1.add(LSTM(32))
model_glove1.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model_glove1.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model_glove1.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model_glove1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics['accuracy',auc_roc])
model_glove1.fit(data, np.array(train_y), batch_size=32,
epochs=4,
verbose=1,
validation_split=0.1,
shuffle=True)
```

I want to add an additional auxiliary input layer which is present in a dataframe of 27 columns . I want that layer to be concatenated with the output of the LSTM layer. Is it possible ? If so how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using the code, please check the secondary input has the same dimension like output of LSTM layer.

Moreover, in model1_glove.fit() function, you need to provide two inputs

```
def NNStructure():
    initial_input= Embedding(vocabulary_size, 25, input_length=50, weights= 
    [embedding_matrix25],trainable=False) 
    lstm = LSTM(32)(initial_input)   
    secondary_input = Input(shape=(Number_of_row,27))    
    merge = concatenate([lstm, secondary_input])
    first_dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(merge)
    second_dense=Dense(64, activation='relu')(first_dense)
    output=Dense(1, activation='softmax')(second_dense)

    model_glove1 = Model(inputs=[initial_input, secondary_input], outputs=output)
    return model_glove1

model_glove1=NNStructure()
model_glove1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics['accuracy',auc_roc])
model_glove1.fit(x=[data1,data2], y=np.array(train_y), batch_size=32,
epochs=4,
verbose=1,
validation_split=0.1,
shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Got the following error: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 32), (None, 696960, 27)].............I think it has to do with the same thing you asked me to check-  the secondary input has the same dimension like output of LSTM layer. I am quite new to this and don't understand how I can change the shape. Could you help?

Comment: I believe i need to use reshape function from keras.layers but cant figure how I can change shape of LSTM layer from (None,32) to be able to concatenate with (None,696960,27)

Comment: Edit:
lstm = LSTM(32,input_shape=(50,25))(initial_input)
secondary_input = Input(shape=(50,27))    
merge = concatenate([lstm, secondary_input],axis=2)